# Give a common value to similar cells Excel

Tags: excel

I have an Excel sheet with a lot of product names. Some of these names are similar, and I am trying to make a cell that sets the same value on similar names.

Ie:

I have two columns:

```
Product        ProductNo
Nice Jacket    
Nice Jacket
Nice Jacket
Nice Pants
Nice Pants
Nice Cap
```

And I need a way to autopopulate the prodoctno like this:

```
Product        ProductNo
Nice Jacket    100000
Nice Jacket    100000
Nice Jacket    100000
Nice Pants     100001
Nice Pants     100001
Nice Cap       100002
```

Comment: I have answered your question. If you have any doubts, you can let me know, I will edit the answer and help you further. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey follow these steps to meet your requirement -

1. create a table containing unique product name and it's value.
2. Name the table with anything of your choice. In my case, i have named it "Productinfo". Please refer to the image below -

[image]

[image]

3. Now come back to your data, suppose data is in A and B column, write a formula as shown in the image below.

[image]

You are all set! :)